# Subsetting in H2O R

Tags: r, subset, h2o

I have a h2o object.

The standard R for subset

```
sub1<-trans[trans$Type==1,]
```

I tried the same in h2o. It is not working

```
sub1<-trans[trans$Type==1,]
```

I also tried

```
sub1<-h2o.exec(trans[trans$Type==1,])
```

note* trans is a h2o data Object.

Any idea to do it in h2o? Thanks

Comment: Is it from the h2o package?

Comment: yes. it is from h2o package.

Comment: Please take the time to create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Give the code you are using to create your object (or a similar one). This will make it easier to help you. Also, including all the necessary `library()` statements in your example would help show where functions are coming from.

Comment: Ideally, your first command should work. Could you please add the result of the following command: h2o.table(trans$Type)

Comment: It does works but I am doing it for about 100k rows, and it is slow. Any way to improve the performance?

Comment: Found a way myself, `sub1<-trans[trans$type==1,names(trans)]`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is the most "hydrophilic" way to do this but:

```
transType <- trans$Type
sub1 <- trans[transType == 1,]
```

Seems to work for me with no problem.

For a more reproducible example, consider

```
library(h2o)
localH2O <- h2o.init()

prosPath <- system.file("extdata", "prostate.csv", package = "h2o")
prostate.hex <- h2o.importFile(localH2O, path = prosPath)
prostate.hex[prostate.hex$GLEASON == 6,]
```

Comment: `sub1<-h2o.exec(trans[trans$Type==1,rownames(trans)])` surprisingly it improves the speed.

Comment: Do you mean `trans[trans$Type == 1, colnames(trans)]`?

Comment: yeah. a quick typo right there. thanks for correcting me

Comment: Do you have a non-trivial, benchmarked example for the speed differences?