# Conditionally remove rows from H2O frame object in R

Tags: r, dataframe, h2o

I have an H2O frame R object like this

```
h2odf

A | B | C | D
--|---|---|---
1 | NA| 2 | 0
2 | 1 | 2 | 0
3 | NA| 2 | 0
4 | 3 | 2 | 0
```

I want to remove all those rows where B is NA (1st and 3rd row). I have tried

```
na <- is.na(h2odf[,"b"])
h2odf <- h2odf[!na,]
```

and

```
h2odf <- h2odf[!is.na(h2odf$B),]
```

and

```
h2odf <- subset(h2odf, B!=NA)
```

This works for R Dataframe but not H2O. Giving this error:

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 


ERROR MESSAGE:

DistributedException from localhost/127.0.0.1:54321: 'Cannot set illegal UUID value'
```

Desired output is

```
h2odf

A | B | C | D
--|---|---|---
2 | 1 | 2 | 0
4 | 3 | 2 | 0
```

One option I have is to convert it into R Dataframe, remove rows and convert it back to H2O frame. But that is taking long time because input file size is close to 4.5 GB. Is it possible to do this in H2O frame hex object itself?

I am running Rstudio on aws cluster.

Comment: have you tried the subset function? idk what h20 frames are, but its very simple syntactically

Comment: Yes. I have tried this h2odf <- subset(h2odf, B!=NA). Not working. H2O is a platform that makes it faster to apply machine learning algorithms on big data. Doing this using normal R dataframes is very slow. I am using its R library. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/h2o.pdf .    https://www.h2o.ai/h2o/

Comment: oh yeah you need to use subset(h2odf, !is.na(B)) or a column of B perhaps

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried this. Not working.

Comment: if neither the subset function nor x[bool,] approach works, then its probably something specific to this h2odf data type. have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181616/subsetting-in-h2o-r#27296668

Comment: I am running this on RStudio on aws cluster. Getting this error: Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 
  

ERROR MESSAGE:

DistributedException from localhost/127.0.0.1:54321: 'Cannot set illegal UUID value'

Comment: I have tried everything mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005154/conditionally-remove-dataframe-rows-with-r

Comment: can you just convert the object to a data frame?

Comment: Yes. That is possible. But it will take too much time. My input file is more than 4GB. Reading into R dataframe is very slow compared to h2o frame.

Answer (score 1):

```
> class(h2odf)
[1] "H2OFrame"

> h2odf
  A  B C D
1 1 NA 2 0
2 2  1 2 0
3 3 NA 2 0
4 4  3 2 0

[4 rows x 4 columns] 

> h2odf[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(h2odf$B))),]
  A B C D
1 2 1 2 0
2 4 3 2 0

[2 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  :

Comment: @penguin - Never worked on H2O. My answer might not be valid for your query in that case. I can take it off so others can still assist you.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure whether you should remove it. This works for default  R dataframe object. I was hoping that it will work for r h2o frame object also as most of R operations work.

Comment: This is a similar issue but still unresolved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181616/subsetting-in-h2o-r#27296668

Comment: Can you show how to create that `H2O frame`? I have downloaded the required package.

Comment: To convert an existing dataframe to H2O frame use df <- as.h2o(h2odf). To read directly from csv, use df <- h2o.importFile(path = filepath)

Comment: After converting to a `H2OFrame` and running the same commands, I still get the output you are looking for. Please see updated code above.

Comment: Ok. I think I was able to reproduce your issue. Because you have `NA` explicitly in your `H2OFrame`, it is being treated as `character`. Please see the updated code above. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page, : ERROR MESSAGE: Object 'RTMP_sid_b571_28' not found for argument: key

Comment: I think I will need the exact data set to reproduce this particular issue.

Comment: Thanks but actual data is confidential. I am running rstudio on aws cluster. Column B is numeric.

Comment: I won't be able to reproduce the issue in that case. Gave a try though.

Comment: Thanks for that :)